# Probability of Positive Returns

Tags: statistics

I'm doing a project on gambling and I've got a set of returns for various bets. I have 219 data points and I'm trying to determine a formula for the probability that returns are positive after $n$ bets.

The mean return is $7.4$ dollars, with a standard deviation of $224.4$ and a variance of $50,358$. My plan originally was just to use the $z$-scores of the distribution and sum them some how but then I realized that I didn't really know what I was doing.

Here is my data set:

```
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
425
-100
-100
389
-100
-100
725
-100
-100
470
-100
-100
-100
-100
420
-100
-100
-100
354
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
444
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
475
-100
-100
500
-100
400
-100
-100
450
-100
-100
460
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
406
-100
-100
-100
495
390
380
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
435
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
365
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
765
-100
385
-100
415
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
405
-100
540
-100
-100
-100
-100
415
-100
-100
-100
-100
450
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
373
-100
472
-100
-100
-100
385
-100
700
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
501
-100
400
-100
-100
-100
590
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
559
-100
-100
-100
472
-100
444
568
-100
-100
-100
375
-100
500
-100
-100
-100
451
-100
-100
371
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
361
450
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If we assume normality then let$$X_i\sim N(7.4,50358)$$

where the $X_i$'s are independently and identically distributed.

Define

$$Z=X_1+X_2+...+X_n$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
E(Z)
&=E(X_1+...+X_n)\\\\
&=E(X_1)+...+E(X_n)\\\\
&=n\cdot E(X_1)\\\\
&=n\cdot7.4
\end{align*}$$

Similarly

$$\begin{align*}
Var(Z)
&=Var(X_1+...+X_n)\\\\
&=Var(X_1)+...+Var(X_n)\\\\
&=n\cdot Var(X_1)\\\\
&=n\cdot 50358
\end{align*}$$

Then $$Z\sim N(n\cdot7.4, n\cdot50358)$$

and so finally

$$\begin{align*}
P(Z\gt0)
&=1-P(Z\lt0)\\\\
&=1-\Phi\left(\frac{0-n\cdot7.4}{\sqrt{n\cdot50358}}\right)
\end{align*}$$

After closer examination, your data is **extremely** non-normal so you might want to check if it follows another distribution better. I will let someone more qualified bud in. In the meantime, I suggest you un-accept my answer to increase viewership.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I would be very grateful if you ran the model. Should I just post the data set as part of the original question?

Comment: Yes that would be good. You can put the data in your initial question in code.

Comment: I thought your data had the number of bets associated with each return amount?

Comment: Oh, what I posted was the return of each individual bet. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So you have a random variable $X$ that denotes the return from an $individual$ bet and you want to find the probability that the sum of $n$ of these random variables is positive?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok, I will edit my answer upon completion.